# How to improve emitter-follower efficiency?

Tags: amplifier, buffer, emitter-follower, common-collector

I’m trying to wrap my head around the emitter follower.

I’m currently using it to simulate a ~12V AC coming from a intercom ringer (about 700Hz).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNBdbX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My input is a function generator and I would like my output to drive quite a bit of current. Right now the best I could do is drive a few mA but in the process I’m setting my \$R_E\$ on fire.
Is there a way to improve the efficiency of this circuit? Or I’m better off using another buffer?

Comment: This circuit will not work as needed - use standard (two transistors)  class a / ab amplifier

Comment: That's what a Class A amplifier does. Search "Class B" or "Class AB Amplifier" designs.

Comment: That \$R_E\$ just "pisses away" as much current as it can deliver to the output. What you need is an \$R_E\$ that varies its value depending on how much current is needed at the output. That's a job for another transistor. Like a class B (or AB) output stage.

Comment: When your input signal rises, the BJT base rises. When the BJT base rises, it's emitter will actively follow it; accessing collector current to help it pull upward on your output capacitor and load. But when the input signal falls, the BJT base falls too. But the output capacitor voltage, initially, is the same so this "pinches" the BJT's base-emitter junction (turning it off, for the most part -- and in any case collector current cannot drive downward on the emitter.) So the only way the capacitor discharges is via your passive RE. You need small Ohms to make that work = POWER.

Comment: The whole idea is crazy-minded. You will find folks on YouTube doing it. (Big, hurking resistors, too.) That doesn't mean it is a good idea. It's not. You've got active pull-up, passive pull-down. And to make the passive pull-down anything close to as good as the active pull-up, you need to waste horrible amounts of power in RE. Even then, the output is at least somewhat distorted, besides. (Which may be made smaller at the expense of still more wasted power in RE.) You will want a 2-quadrant output stage or its equivalent.

Comment: The maximum efficiency for a resistively loaded class A amplifier is in the range of 12.5% depending upon bias level.

Comment: So the answer to my question is to add a second transistor?

Comment: @gurghet At least one. And a few other parts, too.